# An TileWMS -> TileLayer -> Map -> View based on a WMS `GetTile` request with openlayers only duplicates the same tile on the map

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

Until 2020, I was displaying an *IGN* map with *Openlayers* with this code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS';
import * as olProj from 'ol/proj';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';

@Component({
  selector: 'carte',
  templateUrl: './carte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carte.component.css']
})
export class CarteComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Carte Openlayers. */
  map: Map;
      
  /* Longitude. */
  @Input() longitude: number;
  
  /* Latitude. */
  @Input() latitude: number;
  
  /** Niveau de zoom initial. */
  @Input() zoom: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var ign_source = new TileWMS({
      url: 'http://wxs.ign.fr/cdw20cou9clqe59fvn39rmcu/geoportail/r/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGN', 'TILED': false}
    });
    
    var ign = new TileLayer({
        source: ign_source
    });

    this.map = new Map({
        target: "carte_principale",
        
        view: new View({
            center: olProj.fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
            zoom: this.zoom
        })
    });
    
    this.map.addLayer(ign);
  }
}
```

Then IGN geoportail made big changes for months, and when it went back, I had to adapt my code to use it again.

It documentation looks to use `GetTile` requests to display the map, instead of `GetMap` it was suggesting to use before.
And according to it, I changed my code that way:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  const planIGN =  new TileWMS( {
    url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',

    params: {
      REQUEST: 'GetTile',
      VERSION: '1.0.0',
      LAYER: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
      STYLE: 'normal',
      FORMAT: 'image/png',
      SERVICE: 'WMTS',
      TILEMATRIX: 14,
      TILEMATRIXSET: 'PM',
      TILECOL: 8180,
      TILEROW: 5905
    }});

  const ign = new TileLayer({
     source: planIGN
  });

  this.map = new Map({
     target: 'carte_principale',

     view: new View({
        center: olProj.fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
        zoom: this.zoom
     })
  });

  this.map.addLayer(ign);
}
```

It works... but the display isn't the one expected:

- the same tile is duplicated along the map.
- the latitude/longitude isn't resolved
- the zoom doesn't work

The two last points, because I don't know how to parametrize the request correctly.

[image]

When I attempt that displaying with *QGis* (where the map is shown fine) using its network tool, it see that kind of requests exchanged, so I'm not so far:

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2&STYLE=normal&FORMAT=image/png&TILEMATRIXSET=PM&TILEMATRIX=13&TILEROW=2946&TILECOL=4093
```

*Openlayers* is powerful, but often tricky for me:
what should I change to have a better behavior?

---

Epilog: after @Solomon and others replied to my question, here the code I've eventually produced and that worked:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import Tile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import WMTS from 'ol/source/WMTS';
import WMTSTileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/WMTS';

import {fromLonLat, get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj';
import {getWidth, getTopLeft} from 'ol/extent';

@Component({
  selector: 'carte',
  templateUrl: './carte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carte.component.css']
})
export class CarteComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Carte Openlayers. */
  map: Map;

  /* Longitude. */
  @Input() longitude: number;

  /* Latitude. */
  @Input() latitude: number;

  /** Niveau de zoom initial. */
  @Input() zoom: number;

  /** Couche Plan IGN V2 */
  planIGNV2: TileLayer<WMTS> = this.couche('https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts', 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
    'EPSG:3857', 'image/png');

  /* Couche : Orthophotos
     orthoPhotos: TileLayer<WMTS> = this.couche('https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts', 'ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS',
     'EPSG:3857', 'image/jpeg')
  */

  ngOnInit() {
    const map = new Map({
      layers: [ this.planIGNV2 ],
      target: 'carte_principale', // id de l'élément HTML
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
        zoom: this.zoom
      })
    });
  }

  /**
   * Crée une couche tuilée WMTS
   * @param url URL
   * @param layer Nom de la couche
   * @param projection Projection à utiliser pour calculer la grille de tuiles (exemple : EPSG:3857)
   * @param format Format d'image à utiliser.
   */
  couche(url: string, layer: string, projection: string, format: string): TileLayer<WMTS> {
    return new Tile({
      source : new WMTS({
        url,
        layer,
        matrixSet: 'PM',
        format,
        style: 'normal',
        tileGrid: this.grilleTuiles(projection)
      })
    });
  }

  /**
   * Renvoie une grille de tuiles
   * @param projection Projection (exemple : EPSG:3857)
   */
  grilleTuiles(projection: string): WMTSTileGrid {
    const proj = getProjection(projection);
    const maxResolution = getWidth(proj.getExtent()) / 256;
    const projectionExtent = proj.getExtent();

    const resolutions = [];
    const matrixIds = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      matrixIds[i] = i.toString();
      resolutions[i] = maxResolution / Math.pow(2, i);
    }

    return new WMTSTileGrid( {
      origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent), // coin supérieur gauche
      resolutions,
      matrixIds
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: To use WMTS you must configure a WMTS source as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-ign.html  TileWMS does not support WMTS,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are not doing this correctly at all.
You are just asking for one single tile, the one located at  TILECOL: 8180, TILEROW: 5905

Make use of this code:

```
        const projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326');
        const projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
        // The matrixes start at 2 tiles wide, 1 tile high (OR WHATEVER YOU HAVE IN THE API DOCUMENTATION)
        const size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256 / 2; // or ol.extent.getHeight(projectionExtent) / 256
        const resolutions = new Array(12);
        const matrixIds = new Array(12);

        for (let z = 0; z < 12; ++z) {
            // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
            resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
            matrixIds[z] = "EPSG:4326:" + z;
        }

        map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                url: <your_url_tile_provider>
                projection: projection,
                layer: <your layer name>,
                matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
                format: <your format>,
                style: <your style>,
                tileGrid : new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                    origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent), // topLeftCorner
                    resolutions: resolutions,
                    matrixIds: matrixIds
                }),
            }),
            opacity: 0.7, <whatever you want>
        }));
```